# How to open a popup on click of anchor tag among multiple anchor tags and display database info related to it?

Tags: php, javascript

How to open a popup on click of anchor tag among multiple anchor tags and display database info related to it? I have to get current id of that anchor tag which user has clicked ?

Comment: Are you using straight javascript or JQuery? What you're asking isn't necessarily easy to accomplish for a beginner, but the community would like to see you atleast make an effort before asking for help. Do you have any code where you've attempted this you can share with us?

Answer (score 0):

YES you need to try something first! Stack overflow works well when you run into a specific programming problem not a "how do I do something, I haven't tried anyhthing yet"

If you have a lot of anchors that  user can click on you can make an ajax call for each anchor to get the related information.

in javascript psuedo code something like

```
function getInfoForAnchor(anchorId) {
   response = makeAjaxCallForAnchorId(ancorId);
   if response is successfull open a tab
   alert(response.text)
}
```

Many users do not like to be pop upped on though.  Maybe you could rethink your ux?  A new window might be better approach where you just load a url somethign like http://yoursite.com/?anchor_id=3  and display the corresponding information.
Or even better than that (imo) is on click having a spot on the current page fill with the infomration you want your user to see! this would require an ajax call like above.  Unless you load all the information on page load.  goodluck!

Comment: i am using javascript for opening popup and getting clicked anchor id.The thing is that i am not able to fetch clicked anchor id via php.

Comment: <a href="home.php" id="<?php echo $key1['id']; ?>" value="<?php echo $key1['id'];?>" onclick="win(this);popup('popUpDiv');">more info</a>